# How do I automatically restart a Minecraft Spigot server in the event of a crash or /stop when using screen?

Tags: bash, server, automation, minecraft, restart

I use screen to run my minecraft spigot server on linux so that I can do other tasks at the same time on the same console.
When using screen, all restart scripts described on the Internet and the [Spigot wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-installation/) no longer worked. The "/restart" command never worked either.
So how do I restart the server automatically after a short time if it crashes or I shut it down with "/stop" ingame?

Comment: Create a script to check if spigot server is running, if not, start the server. Put this script on cron to run every X minutes

Answer (score 15):

## Tutorial

A friend wrote a bash script to automatically restart a minecraft (spigot) server in the event of a crash or with the command "/stop" when using screen. 
There are several seconds to cancel the restart with Enter.
In addition, the exit codes of the previous session are written to a file, which can be used to understand when and why a server has crashed or restarted.

You need two files:

1. "start.sh"

```bash
#!/bin/sh

screen -d -m -S "mc_spigot_server" ./startserver.sh
```

2. "startserver.sh"

```bash
#!/bin/bash

JAR=spigot-1.15.2.jar
MAXRAM=1024M
MINRAM=1024M
TIME=20


while [ true ]; do
    java -Xmx$MAXRAM -Xms$MINRAM -jar $JAR nogui
    if [[ ! -d "exit_codes" ]]; then
        mkdir "exit_codes";
    fi
    if [[ ! -f "exit_codes/server_exit_codes.log" ]]; then
        touch "exit_codes/server_exit_codes.log";
    fi
    echo "[$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %T")] ExitCode: $?" >> exit_codes/server_exit_codes.log
    echo "----- Press enter to prevent the server from restarting in $TIME seconds -----";
    read -t $TIME input;
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        break;
    else
        echo "------------------- SERVER RESTARTS -------------------";
    fi
done
```

You can change the start parameters by changing the variables:

> JAR = server filename
>
> MAXRAM = maximum RAM
>
> MINRAM = minimum RAM
>
> TIME = time in seconds until server restarts automatically

Execute the following in the directory:

```bash
chmod +x start.sh startserver.sh
```

Run your start up script:

```bash
./start.sh
```

- To leave the minecraft screen press Ctrl + A + D
- To reconnect to minecraft screen use `screen -r`

Did you discover any mistakes or do you disagree? Help me do it better.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with this script since I changed os from Linux Centos 8 to Ubuntu 18.

When I was using this script to restart my Minecraft server in Linux Centos 8 I had no problem; since I changed OS to Ubuntu, I can't stop the auto restart script.

I just translated in Italian a few text rows.

This is what I see in the screen during the auto restart:

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: This does not appear to be a answer to OP. consider earning enough creds and add your comments to the OP instead

Comment: Also, please do not post screenshots of text but the text itself.

Comment: I couldn't find this log in the server logs and the pnly way to have some "proofs" of what's happening was this way.

I'm new in this website so i'm not familiar with how to answer/reply to a post.
I just needed some help here for this script

Comment: I don't know why you have this error messages (./vanilla.sh not fount) but for your problem: You can still exit with Ctrl+C instead of "enter".
Does it help?

Comment: @PaulBecker I can exit from the screen but the server runs in background and I can't stop it anymore. The only way is rebooting the machine